# how to display current month, year in javascript using div

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I'm trying to get a jquery or java-script code for displaying the current month and year in a div, but unable so far. I mean I want to display the current month and year in this format:`October 2012` so that every month I don't need to edit it or anything.

I saw many questions here, but none shows how to display the variable in a div.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Your help and ideas are much appreciated

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't natively implement `strftime`, so you'll have to do something a bit less elegant:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];;
    var date = new Date();

    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
};
```

I'm assuming that you have an element with an `id` of `date` somewhere in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and added a div with id date, but it didn't work. any idea what I missed?

Comment: It works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KwARm/. How are you including it into your HTML?

Comment: well, it is acting weird in my end. I placed the JavaScript code on the head and the div in the body. Then executed the test and nothing showed up...

Comment: You probably aren't waiting for the DOM to be ready. See my edit.

Comment: Careful. There is a repeated semicolon at the end of the array declaration.

Answer (score 12):

there's no inbuild function in javascript to get full name of month. You can create an array of month names and use it to get full month name for e.g

```
var m_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 
               'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
               'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

d = new Date();
var n = m_names[d.getMonth()];
```

Answer (score 9):

Get current Date, month, year or ETC....

```
new Date().getDate()          // Get the day as a number (1-31)
new Date().getDay()           // Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
new Date().getFullYear()      // Get the four digit year (yyyy)
new Date().getHours()         // Get the hour (0-23)
new Date().getMilliseconds()  // Get the milliseconds (0-999)
new Date().getMinutes()       // Get the minutes (0-59)
new Date().getMonth()         // Get the month (0-11)
new Date().getSeconds()       // Get the seconds (0-59)
new Date().getTime()          // Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at moment()  http://momentjs.com

```
moment().format('MMMM YYYY');
```

Comment: Thanks @chovy. I will try it out and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

> Using this you can get the only current month

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth()+1;
```

the value of n is 3 (like current month is march)

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt = new Date();
var m = ['January','February', 'March', ...][dt.getMonth()]; //you get the idea...
var y = dt.getFullYear();
$('<div>').html(m + " " + y).appendTo(document);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format your date with JqueryUI (if you already use this). Datepicker provides formatting:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate("MM yy", date);
```

To insert your date in a div you can use this function:

```
$("#divId").append($.datepicker.formatDate("MM yy", new Date()));
```

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try it out and see how it goes.