# How to get Current Month and Year in string format in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Expected Output: **01-2019** or **02-2019** in string.

I need this in my Angular .ts file. Not in the HTML view file.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962468/angularjs-display-current-date

Comment: @Code_maniac but I need it in my .ts file. Not in the html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display current month, year in javascript using div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757911/how-to-display-current-month-year-in-javascript-using-div) and [How to get year/month/day from a date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013255)

Comment: Yes I've searched that. I can do that. But, when I am going to format the date in my Ionic Angular .ts file, it doesn't work as my regular way. @adiga

Comment: What doesn't work? Get the month, Get the year, add a hyphen in between

Comment: @adiga But I need 01,02 for single digit month. And I am expecting much more pimplier method, where I don't need to concatenate the strings.

Comment: Mate, every possible combination of date format has been asked on stackoverflow. `dd-mm-yyyy` isn't something new. Just google and make an attempt before asking a question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp):

`this.curdate = (new Date().getMonth() + 1).toString() + '-' + new Date().getFullYear().toString();`

Note that `new Date().getMonth()` start from 0 to 11 so you need to +1 to make it 1 to 12.

### Update:

To add leading 0 based on related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date) you can do: `'0' + (new Date().getMonth() + 1).toString().slice(-2)`

Explanation:

Since `'0'` is not a number but a string when you add (`+`) with another string then it would be concatenated. Then `.slice(-2)` gives us the last two characters of the string. If it's single digit then it would be `0x`month, if it's double digits then it would be 0 + `xx` month which are returned.

See snippet for example:

```js
var d = '0' + (new Date().getMonth() + 1).toString().slice(-2) + '-' + new Date().getFullYear().toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Alternatively if you don't want a trailing 0 on double digit months (Oct, Nov, Dec) you could do a little checking based on month digit length: `(new Date().getMonth() + 1).length > 1 ? new Date().getMonth() + 1 : '0' + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)`

```js
var month = (new Date().getMonth() + 1).length > 1 ? new Date().getMonth() + 1 : '0' + (new Date().getMonth() + 1);
var date = (month).toString().slice(-2) + '-' + new Date().getFullYear().toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: @AbhijitM.Abhi Again, if you do some research, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date

Comment: @Mukyuu Can you please, check your answer again? It was correct at the January month. But, in this February it doesn't get the current month and year. Hopefully, you will update the code.

Comment: Done, it's `(` miswrapping. My bad.

Comment: That's great my Mate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in date pipe:

`{{date | date:'MM-dd'}}`

and pass your own format.
**Update**
Try something like for a JS-only solution:

```
m = new Date().getMonth().toString() + 1;
y = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
return m + '-' + y;
```

Comment: It works for html file. But I want to format the date in my .ts file.

Comment: I would have told you the same as the accpeted answer, so I think the problem is solved for you?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can import `DatePipe`, or `FormatDate` into your component.ts.

1) [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {   

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'MM-yyyy');
  }
}
```

Do not forget to add DatePipe to your providers in your module.

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

2) [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate):

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return formatDate(date, 'MM-yyyy', this.locale);
  }
}
```